# Is it possible to change width of tab symbol in textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea, whitespace

By default tab symbol in textarea equals to the width of 8 spaces. Is it possible to change this value to 4 for example?

I am mostly interested in using this in Chrome browser.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the following css for Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 21+ and Opera 10.6+

```css
textarea,
pre {
    -moz-tab-size : 4;
      -o-tab-size : 4;
         tab-size : 4;
}
```

Comment: +1 This does work in moz, I am still interested in a Chrome CSS solution.

Comment: Took me a moment to realise that Chrome's implementation is unprefixed (ie `tab-size` not `-webkit-tab-size`). More details available on the MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/tab-size

Comment: Ahh yes. When I originally wrote the answer it was not yet available in Chrome. '-webkit-tab-size' was included so it would work in future versions of Chrome. However, Webkit omitted the prefix in its first implementation of the tab-size property. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This now works in chrome without any prefix.